# How to replace \n with <br /> without affecting other tags?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML textarea containing both \n and other HTML tags. E.g. `<b></b>`.

I need to replace `\n` without affecting any other embedded html tags.

I tried the solutions below but it cuts out the closing bracket of other tags.

This: `myTextArea.value.replace(/[\n]/g,'<br />');`

Gives me this: `<b>Hello World!</b`.

This: `replace(/\n/g, "<br />");`
Produces the same results.

Note the `</b`.

Comment: Shouldn't be the case unless you have tags with newlines in it the following *will* work: `myTextArea.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')` But remember that this will return a new string, which you will need to assign to a variable, eg: `myTextArea.value = myTextArea.value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')`

Comment: I made you a testcase: `'<b>hello\nworld\n!</b>'.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') === "<b>hello<br>world<br>!</b>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put n+:

```
.replace(/(\n+)/g, '<br />');
```

Actually you need to remove /r too:

```
 message.replace(/(\r)/g, '').replace(/(\n+)/g, '<br/>');
```

Comment: No need for capturing groups, and no need for two replace calls, just use the zero or one time metacharacter (`?`): `message.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />')` Using `+` (repeat one or more times) will change the output: `'\n\n\n'.replace(/\n+/g, '<br>') === "<br>"`, while: `'\n\n\n'.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') === "<br><br><br>"`